# BootStrap Table With Dynamic Data using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a Bootstrap Table with JQuery.

I tried to help myself but still could not get a solution.

Please check out [this link](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/index.html).

Here I need the data to be dynamic.

For example, there can be a situation where fields can get created dynamically.

Sometimes there can be three columns and sometimes there can be four columns based on the JSON object.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide me with fiddle example.

Comment: Dixit Ji, to fulfill your requirement try jquery datatable. https://datatables.net/

Comment: Hi Mayank Pandey Thanks for your response. But datatables is liscenced version. You can verify here https://editor.datatables.net/purchase/index so i cannot use it in my application. Even can you provide me some example with datatables with that dynamic feature?

Comment: Bro only editor version is paid (which is used to give in-line editing), rest is free to use.

Comment: But I need that functionality as well editing,exporting data etc.

Comment: you can implement your own in-line editing by spending half an hour on it. Rest is free.

Refer this: https://github.com/pandeyz/Jquery-Datatable---Server-Side-with-Custom-Inline-Editing